# "Es machte ihm jedoch niemand auf" vs "Jedoch machte ihm niemand auf"

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, expletiva

I came across the following (untranslated) example in a reference work:

> Er klingelte.  Es machte ihm jedoch niemand auf.

I'm not familiar with the form of the second sentence (the *es* at the beginning, in particular).

I would have written it like this instead

> Jedoch machte ihm niemand auf.

Is my form incorrect?  Or odd-sounding?

Also, I would like to see other examples of this form.  For example, could one say

> Er fragte.  Es antwortete ihm jedoch niemand.
>   Er erkundigte sich.  Es gab ihm jedoch niemand Auskunft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence *Jedoch machte ihm niemand auf.* is perfectly fine. But this form is only possible when you have a particle which allows this in the sentence. *Doch*, *noch* et al. do, but e.g the common *aber* **does not**.

An adverbial (of time or location or reason…) in the sentence can also go to the front and suppress the otherwise needed *es*.

> Er klingelte. *Dennoch* machte ihm niemand auf.
>
> Er klingelte. *Auch nach einer Weile* machte ihm niemand auf. Er klingelte erneut.
>
> Er klingelte. *An der Tür* machte ihm niemand auf. Stattdessen ging ein Fenster auf.
>
> Er klingelte. *Wegen seiner ständigen Klingelei* fluchte im Haus jemand.

When you don't have something to put at the front, you need the *Es*.

> Er klingelte. *Es* machte ihm niemand auf.

But of course, you can combine *es* with particles and adverbials, too.

> Er klingelte. *Es* machte ihm dennoch niemand auf.
>
> Er klingelte. *Es* machte ihm auch nach einer Weile niemand auf. Er klingelte erneut.
>
> Er klingelte. *Es* machte ihm an der Tür niemand auf. Stattdessen ging ein Fenster auf.
>
> Er klingelte. *Es* fluchte wegen seiner ständigen Klingelei im Haus jemand.

As stated above, **aber** is no help.

> Er klingelte. *Es* machte ihm aber niemand auf.
>
> Er klingelte. Aber *es* machte ihm niemand auf.

The *es* is required in the second sentence.

Comment: Thank you!  How about "Er klingelte.  Niemand machte ihm auf."?  Is this *grammatically* correct?  (I realize it is not semantically equivalent to the original, since it does not have the "jedoch"/"aber" bit.)

Comment: Yes, this is also possible because you have put the subject *Niemand* in front. It's not possible to drop in *jedoch*, *dennoch*, *aber* and so on into that sentence however. Those need the other word order.